# Draw L.circle in a custom pane

Tags: leaflet

I want to draw L.circle in a custom pane but I am using mapbox.js and hence the leaflet version 0.7.7.How can I draw L.circle in a custom pane? Do we have to copy some js files from the 1.0 version of leaflet? Please help me and explain how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

In leaflet source file search for function _initPanes(). Inside the function create a new custom pane and attach it to mapPane.

```
pane.myCustomPane = this._createPane('leaflet-mycustom-pane-css');
```

Update L.Circle code to attach the circle to your custom mapPane.

Comment: I know how to make custom pane.The question here is  how to attach the circles to that pane?